# Invalid Salt when using bcrypt.checkpw

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am working on a user authentification app using Django. The app allows the user to create an account then login. However, on the login side i am getting an error when checking for the user password using bcrypt.checkpw

I tried printing the value of the user password and the one saved on the data base. I am using SQLite for the database by the way

```
print(request.POST['login_password'].encode())
print(user.password)
```

here is the output:

```
b'87654321'
b'$2b$12$bQ6tEDKh.tOJnnPAj84Xe.BZnGi9kI.Sc6Q4gFPeTLw9x53VSVQOW'
```

I also tried:

```
print(request.POST['login_password'].encode())
print(user.password.encode())

b'87654321'
b"b'$2b$12$bQ6tEDKh.tOJnnPAj84Xe.BZnGi9kI.Sc6Q4gFPeTLw9x53VSVQOW'"
```

To creat user:

```
user = MasjeedUser.objects.create(first_name=request.POST['first_name'],last_name=request.POST['last_name'],password=bcrypt.hashpw(request.POST['password'].encode(), bcrypt.gensalt()),email=request.POST['email'])
```

to query password:

when i use

```
if bcrypt.checkpw(request.POST['login_password'].encode(),user.password)
```

i get as an error: Unicode-objects must be encoded before checking

when i tried

```
if bcrypt.checkpw(request.POST['login_password'].encode(),user.password.encode())
```

i get as an error: invalid salt

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking here. The way to check a password is to use the [`user.check_password`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/passwords/#django.contrib.auth.hashers.check_password) method if you have a User already, or the main [`authenticate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate) function which takes a username and password and returns a User if one matches.

Comment: @Daniel what I am asking here is: does anyone knows why I am getting the invalid salt when invoking bcrypt.checkpw

Answer (score 0):

The reason you have an invalid salt is that you have an extra `b'...'` around the hashed password. That's because the result of `hashpw` is a bytestring, and Django will automatically call `str` on anything passed into a charfield that is not a string. You would need to decode it first.

But in any case **you must not do any of this**. Although bcrypt is a perfectly good hashing library, there is no reason for you to duplicate the functionality that Django gives you; by doing so, you will almost certainly introduce new security vulnerabilities. Don't do this. Inherit your MasjeedUser from the AbstractUser or AbstractBaseUser models in django.contrib.admin, and use their `set_password` and `check_password` methods.